# How do I get $near to work in Flask-mongoalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-mongoengine

I have been trying to work on fetching events from my mongoDB database that are close to the current user's location

I have tried to reformat my Model scheme to contain [type: "Point"] and even arranged my longitude and latitude into a list.
I also tried adding "2dsphere" indexes using meta to my Model based on what I saw in mongo-alchemy documentation.

## My Model

class Event(db.Document):

```
meta = {
    'indexes': [
        ("*location.coordinates", "2dsphere")
    ]
}

user_id = db.StringField()
uuid = db.StringField()
name = db.StringField()
address = db.StringField()
start_time = db.DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.datetime.now())
end_time = db.DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.datetime.now())
location = db.DictField(db.AnythingField())
```

## This is now my main query code

```
def get(self):
    latitude = float(request.args.get('lat'))
    longitude = float(request.args.get('long'))

    print(longitude);
    print(latitude);

    event = Event.query.filter({"location" :
   { "$near" :
        {
        "$geometry" : {
           "type" : "Point",
           "coordinates" : [longitude, latitude] },
        "$maxDistance" : 4000
     }
   }
}).first()
    print(event);
```

[2019-01-15 23:20:59,797] ERROR in app: Exception on /v1/event [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restplus/api.py", line 325, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restplus/resource.py", line 44, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/media/creative_joe/3004586c-9a2d-4cb0-8a5f-d41fe99afc05/home/creative_joe/MonkeyMusic.server/app/views/main.py", line 323, in get
    "$maxDistance" : 4000
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoalchemy/query.py", line 139, in first
    for doc in iter(self):
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoalchemy/query.py", line 412, in next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoalchemy/query.py", line 416, in _next_internal
    value = next(self.cursor)
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mongoalchemy/py3compat.py", line 41, in next
    return it.**next**()
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1189, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1104, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 982, in __send_message
    helpers._check_command_response(first)
  File "/home/creative_joe/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: error processing query: ns=heroku_c9gg06k0.EventTree: GEONEAR  field=location maxdist=4000 isNearSphere=0
Sort: {}
Proj: {}
 planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query

Comment: Last Line is unable to find index, check whether you created an geo2d index on column location or not.

Comment: I was able to fix it, before I was using flask-mongoalchemy but I had to switch to python's mongoengine and it was able to accept the meta data I was passing.